# android studio terminal not install gradlew

Tags: android, gradle

im trying too use commad "gradlew install" in android studio 3.0 terminal but it fails and show errors. any one an help?

[image]

my gradle configuration at top level like this:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.2'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the steps properly for setting up Bintray?

I think you have missed the below step

https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin#gradle--21

And one more problem in downloading gradle plug-in is, you haven't added maven url in `buildscript -> repositories` and `allprojects -> repositories` sections.

```
maven { 
    url 'https://maven.google.com' 
}
```

I hope this information helps you.

Comment: tnks uma. but google() doesnt work as maven { 
    url 'https://maven.google.com' 
}?

Comment: Failed to download SHA1 for resource 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom'.
            > For input string: "<!"
i got this error

Comment: If you are using Android studio 3.0 or higher, then use google() and maven, otherwise, try with maven url